# Terminating a Future and getting the intermediate result

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka

I have a long-running Scala `Future` that operates as follows:

1. Calculate initial result
2. Improve result
3. If no improvement then terminate, else goto 2

After receiving an external signal (meaning the `Future` won't have any a priori knowledge about how long it's supposed to run for), I would like to be able to tell the `Future` to terminate and give me its intermediate result.  I can do this using some sort of side channel (note: this is a Java program using `Akka`, hence the reason I'm creating a Scala future in Java along with all of the attendant boilerplate):

```
public void doCalculation(AtomicBoolean interrupt, AtomicReference output) {
    Futures.future(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() {
            Object previous = // calculate initial value
            output.set(previous);
            while(!interrupt.get()) {
                Object next = // calculate next value
                if(/* next is better than previous */) {
                    previous = next;
                    output.set(previous);
                } else return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }, TypedActor.dispatcher());
}
```

This way whoever is calling `doCalculation` can get intermediate values via `output` and can terminate the `Future` via `interrupt`.  However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without resorting to side channels, as this is going to make it somewhat difficult for somebody else to maintain my code.  We're using Java 7.

Comment: This seems more suitably modeled as a Reactive Stream (akka stream, RxJava, whatever), which spits out intermediate results before calling onComplete when it's totally done.  Then you don't have to cancel it, you just unsubscribe if you don't care for further refinements.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound much like a `Future` to me.  Consider instead a `Runnable` that simply updates an `AtomicReference` field.  Your runnable can update the reference as often as needed, and callers can poll the field whenever they want.

You could have your class implement [`Supplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html) if you want it to expose a standard interface for getting a value.